# Yii2 model load Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class require does not exist'

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using **Yii2 advanced**; and have a problem.

**Code:**

```
$model = \Yii::createObject($this->modelClass);
if ($model->load($temp, '') && $model->validate()) {
    $data = $model;
}
```

`$temp` - is model data array;

`$this->modelClass` - dynamic model classname;

Code runs in **cli mode** (Yii2 console application), `modelClass` - model from `backend` application.

And it's **crashed** in `load` method:

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class require does not exist'

in /path/to/project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:422
```

It's weird, because model `Brand` **works**, but similar other models do not. However the model objects are created successfully.

**UPDATE Category model code**

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

/**
 * Category model
 */
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
  public static function tableName()
  {
    return '{{%category}}';
  }

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
  public function attributes()
  {
    return [
        'id',
        'parent_id',
        'name',
        'image',
    ];
  }

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
  public function attributeLabels()
  {
    return [
        'id' => \Yii::t('backend/model', 'ID'),
        'parent_id' => \Yii::t('backend/model', 'Parent cat ID'),
        'name' => \Yii::t('backend/model', 'Name'),
        'image' => \Yii::t('backend/model', 'Image'),
    ];
  }

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        ['name', 'require'],
        [['name', 'image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['id', 'parent_id'], 'integer'],
        ['parent_id', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
        ['parent_id', 'default', 'value' => 0],
    ];
  }

 /**
  * Method select parent category
  * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
  */
  public function getParent()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(static::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
  }
}
```

Comment: other models are in the same namespace?

Comment: Can you show us what's behind `$this->modelClass`?

Comment: All models in same namespace: `backend\models`.

I have two models: **Brand** and **Category**, so `$this->modelClass` equals:

`backend\models\Brand`

`backend\models\Category`

And I can get model's class short name by PHP Reflection before `load` method.

Comment: Show us the code of model that does not work

Comment: Added, same model **Brand** works good.

Comment: Well show `var_dump($this->modelClass)`, and where it's created/filled since there is no such attribute in yii2. Other code is actually irrelevant. Maybe you need `ClassName::::className()` instead?

Comment: `$this->modelClass` - just string: 'backend\\models\\Brand' or 'backend\\models\\Category', and I can create model, get className, get className by Reflection method before `load`, but Reflection crushed in \yii\base\Model class

Comment: getParent() method has been generated by gii?

Comment: No, I wrote all code by myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So stupid error.

In model's rules I wrote:

```
['name', 'require'],
```

And get exception:

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class require does not exist'

in /path/to/project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:422
```

But valid name of validator is **required** - has `d` at the end.

**IMHO** that error is not clearly for understanding.

Comment: I also had an error in my rules causing this error, mine was not putting the list of safe attributes in their own array for a particular rule. `[['attribute1', 'attribute2'], 'safe']`

Comment: In recent versions of Yii2, it throws a `yii\di\NotInstantiableException`. I found out the hard way after using the rule `exists` where it should've been `exist`.

Answer (score 0):

create an object with container,you should set class,you create object by array('class'=>$this->modelClass);

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to create an ActiveRecord object from `$this->modelClass`, where modelClass is dynamic text string try this:

```
$className = (string)$this->modelClass;
$model = new $className;

if ($model->load($temp, '') && $model->validate()) {
    $data = $model;
}
```

modelClass MUST be exactly the namespace of the class being instantiated. do a breakpoint on the $className assignment line to ensure the value being used is indeed the namespace desired.